# using selenium+python+chromedriver+headless-chrome under aws lambda, chrome driver not loading

Tags: python, selenium, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I'm desperate to have selenium+python+chromedriver+headless-chrome working under AWS lambda, the code below works in cloud9 but once launched in a lambda function, it keeps stuck on line :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CURR_BIN_DIR+"chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

chromedriver and headless-chrome are in version 87
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os,sys
import subprocess
import shutil
import time

CURR_BIN_DIR = os.getcwd() + "/bin/"


def lambda_handler(event, context):
            chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--no-cache')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
            chrome_options.binary_location = CURR_BIN_DIR + "headless-chromium"
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(CURR_BIN_DIR+"chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
            driver.get("https://www.divid.fr")
            text_area = driver.find_element_by_id("about").text.strip()
            print(text_area)
            driver.close()
            return text_area
```

thanks!

Comment: I get no error, just "Task timed out"

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by installing "old" versions of headless-chrome

V1.0.0-53 :
https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-53/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip

and chromedriver 2.41 :
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip

but I still wonder why something works on cloud9 (EC2) and not in a lambda function !